# How to use mongoose or mongodb to check for repeated data (Node.js + Express)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, web-applications, mongoose

I was wondering if there was a way to check for repeated values before entering them into the database using mongodb and mongoose. I am basically looking for a way to validate the data in a sense that the data is not repeated so I don't waste space. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction or show me a a solution, thank you.

App.js:

```
    var print = require('./print');
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var config = require('./config.js');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render("post");
    print("All is in order");
})

app.listen(config.port, function() {
   print(`listening on ${config.port}`);
})

MongoClient.connect(config.localUrl, function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
      return;
    }
    var collection = db.collection('users');
    app.post('/post', function(req, res) {

      var name = req.body.name
      var email = req.body.email
      res.send(`You sent the name ${name} and the email ${email}`);
      var user1 = {};
      user1.name = name;
      user1.email = email;
      //validate no repeated values
      collection.insert(user1, function(err,result){
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('The Results', result);
          db.close();
        }
      })
    })

  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use $setOnInsert
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#op._S_setOnInsert with upsert:true.

Comment: How so, the only examples only use the update function (sorry this may be a stupid question but, I am new to mongodb).

Comment: You can also make a query from node ad if query returns null, this mean you don't have stored document. Now, you can insert new document.